# Does the calling stack in python's shared between the threads or the processes in multithreading and multiprocessing respectively?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, callstack

I am writing a code in python which includes some `multiprocessing` and `multithreading`.

My question is: **Does the threads or the processes share the same call stack?**

I am using the `inspect` module and I'm afraid that it will return me the wrong value in `inspect.stack()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they don't, subprocesses get forked/spawned as separate entities so each Process starts off effectively as a completely new Python instance.

Python hides away some of the nastiness of that by transparently pickling/unpickling data to be transferred between processes but they all get their own stack, their own GIL and all that goes with it.

Multithreading is a different story - threads do share the underlying stack but Python partitions them to appear as each has their own stack so `inspect.stack()` results can be confusing/unpredictable..